# send POST request with body dictionary in afnetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to ask how to send an POST Request with body using AFNetworking 3.0.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: check AFNetworking documentation http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html.  you can use convenient method [AFHTTPSessionManager NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(nullable id)parameters success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id _Nullable responseObject))success failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError *error))failure].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [AFNetworking's GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-an-upload-task-for-a-multi-part-request-with-progress):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];

    //Set the request body here

} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
          uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
          progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
              // This is not called back on the main queue.
              // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  //Update the progress view
                  [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
              });
          }
          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
              if (error) {
                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              } else {
                  NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
              }
          }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

---

**Edit**

The above answer is useful especially if you want to set a custom request body.

If you only need to POST a simple set of parameters you can do it like this:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];

[manager POST:@"http://exaple.com/path" parameters:@{@"param1" : @"foo", @"anotherParameter" : @"bar"} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    //success block

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    //failure block

}];
```

Comment: i want to post a string that is a token only not an image